# Dissimilar behavior of async-await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have stumbled upon a strange behavior of async-await.

Example code:

```
public class foo
{
    public async static Task<myobj> method1()
    {
        var result = await method2();

        return result;
    }

    private async static Task<myobj> method2()
    {
        // omitted for brevity.
    }
}

public class bar
{
    public void caller()
    {
        var result = foo.method1().Result;

        pass(result);
    }
}
```

This freezes the UI. The solution is to implement async-await on caller().

But how about this:

```
public class foo
{
    public static myobj method1()
    {
        var result = method2().Result;

        return result;
    }

    private async static Task<myobj> method2()
    {
        // omitted for brevity.
    }
}

public class bar
{
    public void caller()
    {
        var result = foo.method1();

        pass(result);
    }
}
```

This works freely.

What is different with private call vs. the one made to upstream method from other class?

Comment: This exact situation is described here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the first case is [described in great details by Stephen Cleary in his blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The deadlock occurs at `await method2()`. The `await` continuation was posted to the UI thread's synchronization context via `SynchronizationContext.Post`. But the UI thread is already blocked waiting at this line: `foo.method1().Result`. The message pump is blocked and the continuation callback never gets pumped and invoked, deadlock.

In the second case, I don't see `await` anywhere. I.e., the code as you shown it doesn't do any asynchrony. I guess that's why it works.